# DynamoDB not updating despite success returned on Lambda update function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

For some reason, my Lambda function APPEARS to be working but just fails to update the entry in the database. Here's my Lambda function, which I've confirmed is receiving the correct data via console.logs. I have some similar functions for GET/POST/DELETE operations that work completely fine, so I know that the DB connection is there. It just fails to update this column for some reason.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.run = async (event) => {

let category = event.category
let draggedRev = event.draggedRev
let targetRev = event.targetRev

let tmpDrag = Object.assign({}, draggedRev)

if (category == 'topfive') {

    var params = {
        TableName: 'reviews',
        Key:{
            "id": draggedRev.id
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET #attrName = :attrValue",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#attrName" : "topfive"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":attrValue": {
                "S": (parseInt(targetRev.topfive) + 5).toString()
            } 
        }
    };

    console.log("Updating the item...");
   await client.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    })

}

return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,x-requested-with,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(event)
};
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You should try awaiting on a promise by calling `.promise()` on the `DocumentClient` method instead.

```
try {
    const data = await client.update(params).promise();
    console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
}
```

Also, did you try without providing the types to `ExpressionAttributeValues`?

```
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":attrValue": (parseInt(targetRev.topfive) + 5).toString()
}
```

Comment: Could I ask why, sir ?? I'm having this kind of problem using typeorm